# gaussianblur transform not found in torchvision.transforms

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I have written the following data augmentation pipeline for Pytorch:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.GaussianBlur(11, sigma=(0.1, 2.0)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
        ])
```

But running the above code gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torchvision.transforms' has no attribute 'GaussianBlur'
```

Is GaussianBlur a new feature that has not been included in torchvision yet? Or is it just my torchvision version that is too old?

I found it in the following documentation page: [torchvision.transforms](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur)

Here are my packages versions:

```
torch                    1.6.0+cu101
torchvision              0.7.0+cu101
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this documentation page](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.6.0/search.html?q=gaussian%20blur&check_keywords=yes&area=default), you can look for features on the different versions of pytorch (change version in the upper left corner). It appears that `GaussianBlur` did not exist in pytorch 1.6, and was added in 1.7. Your code should work with the latest version.

If interested, here is the relevant merge commit : https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/2658

Answer (score 0):

You update your pytorch to version 1.7.

`conda update --all` should work (if you use anaconda distribution).

Comment: thank you for your help too (edit: I am not using conda however)